# TCP Server and client application for ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, networking

I am developing a wi-fi module now, and for testing I have only pc with Ubuntu and I am looking for an application for the connecting to my TCP server on the Wi-Fi module, on Windows platform I was using Hercules HW group application, where I could easily connect to the server and receive/send files, so what can I install on my PC with Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For a "raw" TCP connection, take a look at netcat or telnet. There's a good chance you already have them installed, or you can easily get them with apt-get.

I'm not sure what you mean with the receive/send files bit, that depends on whatever service you have running for that on your module (ftp, scp, http, webdav, smb, ...).